# I have a class that i want in all the pages(.aspx pages) of a big site

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a class that i want in all the pages(.aspx pages) of a big site.
How can i do that?

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

namespace masterbinoy.myGlobal
{
public static class myGlobal
{
    static void checkAuthority(string url="~/Default.aspx")
    {

    }
}
}
```

Now i want this name space in all other web pages even when i create a new one just like the default **system** name space

Comment: Have you read about master pages and authentication?

Comment: i am aware about master pages,but i have not read authentication. I would be grateful if you could post some reference url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the namespace to your `web.config` file. Also note that common naming conventions require namespaces to be Pascal cased: `Masterbinoy.MyGlobal`:

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="masterbinoy.myGlobal" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction and suggestion andleer. I almost missed it :)